# How to route all Ethernet traffic to a Serial port on a Linux system?

Tags: ethernet, raspberry-pi, serial-port, udp, packet

How can I route all Ethernet traffic on a Linux system to a Serial port and the opposite?

I want to convert from the first architecture to the second one, as shown in the picture:
[picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dw9Lf.png)

I monitored what packets are exchanged between the PC and Device, and I tried to write Python scripts for each Raspberry pi that creates the appropriate sockets, but it didn't work. I don't know if creating Sockets is the right way or I'm miles away from the solution.
I'm asking for a general guidance.
Do I need a virtual port? Ethernet to Serial converter? Sockets?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Better off on https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/

Comment: A serial port cannot match the bandwidth of Ethernet, so no way it can handle *"all Ethernet traffic"*.  That is a configuration, not an *"architecture"*.  You are probably asking a [XY question](http://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: "All ethernet traffic" sounds like heavy duty, you are right, but I'm actually talking about exchaning packets -string sentences- in three different ports, that is about 1KB every second. Is that so hard for a UART to handle?